# EditText in onDraw()

Tags: android, android-edittext, ondraw

I am aware of how to add EditText but not in the onDraw() function.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new GaugeAnimation((this),10));

    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

    input.setText("hello");
}
```

The above will not work, also, the below doesn't work either:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c){


    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    input.setText("hi");

}
```

so how can i do this? i would basically like to add an editable text box but because i am not using:

```
setContentView(new R.layout.main);
```

its messing up. Any suggestions?

i tried:

```
public class GaugeAnimation extends View{
         public GaugeAnimation(Context context, int value){
            EditText input = new EditText(context);
    input.setId(R.id.input);
 }
}
```

but it still doesn't work what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct your `GaugeAnimation` view, make sure it calls `setId(R.id.input)` for the EditText view you want to use for input. Then your first method will work.

You should be aware that you should not make updates to UI elements from a view's `onDraw` method like you tried.

Comment: sorry i'm a little confused i tried it (read above) and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to inflate the edittext to a view to be able to use it. Without inflating, your edittext isnt instantiated yet.